# Does nodejs support POSIX RegEx character classes

Tags: node.js, regex, posix

Without being sure to what extent this (I believe I am sure of the answer already) kind of question is good style or not, as the post title question says:

Does nodejs support POSIX RegEx character classes?

I see the NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/posix-character-classes.

PreApologies for combining two questions together, but Is there any planning to support it with a built-in extension?  I would kind of like to see them supported.

Comment: link to where I first learned of POSIX RegEx Character Classes: https://regex101.com/, it is super though (opinionation warning) culturally skeptical

Answer (score 0):

The 5/12/2020 NodeJS version 14.2.0 answer is 'No'.

The documentation at https://nodejs.org/api/all.html (took my laptop 12 min to print to 263MB in 700 pages) matches "POSIX" 89 times, mostly related to file system and process threading kind of things, none of which have anything really to do with Regular Expressions.  "RegEx" matched 48 times.  "character class" matched 0 times.

The https://www.npmjs.com/package/posix-character-classes NPM module does look to be pretty good, though I haven't tested it.

It is modular to leave POSIX character classes support as an optional module.